# Windows bat file replacing % with %% dynamically in string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a situation where we are sending user password to different system through bat file and whichworks perfectly fine in most cases.

However, if my password is `fAhCog1H!V2%xaH`, which contains a `%` character we have an issue.

I know `%` need to be escaped by doubling it, `%%`, but I'm not sure how we can dynamically append extra `%` so that it stores as `fAhCog1H!V2%xaH`.

```
java -DTEST_INSTALL_DIR="C:/Program Files" com.xyz.test.installation set_password "sysadmin" "fAhCog1H!V2%xaH" || exit /b
```

Comment: You need to provide code and show where the password is coming from or where it is stored.

Comment: I think this is one one of the worst case scenario for batch-files .  Is there a specific reason why not to use powershell?

Comment: It is easy if you  `enabledelayedexpansion` but show code.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It is not easy. What if my password contains `!appdata!`?

Comment: @anders, still doable, but this question is about `%` and not `!`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard The question is really about escaping strings and if you enable delayed expansion then clearly you have to deal with `!` as well.

Comment: Added code snippet

Comment: @anders let the user provide code and I will show you :).

Comment: that should solve but in my case password is dynamic. so looking for a way to replace % with %% dynamically

Comment: But where do you get the password variables from? Will if always be a single string like this?

Comment: We have a interface which takes password from user and generate bat file to communicate with LDAP system.  it will always be single string like this

Comment: What interface? Another language or a batch as well?

Comment: user interface developed in html and i didn't see any issue with password until it reach the bat file.

Comment: @Anders sorry, I never got around to explaining. anyway, if you do `@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set Inst=!appdata!
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !Inst!` it will set password of `!appdata!` before expansion, then enable expansion it will echo `!appdata!` and not the actual value of system variable `!appdata!`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you call the batch file from your html, but let's say it is  something like:

```
call batchfile.cmd com.xyz.test.installation "sysadmin" "fAhCog1H!V2%xaH"
```

Then your batch will work best if you do this:

```
java -DTEST_INSTALL_DIR="C:/Program Files" %1 set_password %2 %3 || exit /b
```

or enabling `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set Inst=%1
set myuser=%2
set passw=%3
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
java -DTEST_INSTALL_DIR="C:/Program Files" !Inst! set_password !myuser! !passw! || exit /b
```

Note that there are still limitations to this if any of the following are in a password, it will not work. `^` or system variables (before expansion) such as `%appdata%` or `%cd%`
expanded variables will still work, such as `!cd!` or `!appdata!`

Comment: An unchanged password argument string can't be handled by batch at all, think of a password like `ab^c &"&%cd%`

Comment: @jeb yes, you are correct, this is based more on user's password example, if caret are used, or system vaiables then there will be problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gerhard Barnard already said, delayed expansion is a good solution for these types of problems, as the content of delayed expanded variables doesn't change anymore.

When you have the password in a variable like `pwd` then this is *safe*, only the java argument parser can fail, if the password contains quotes or backslashes.

```
java ... set_password "sysadmin" "!pwd!" || exit /b
```

The main problem is to get the password into the `pwd` variable.
But this is more or less easy, double all percents and double all quotes.
The first `DisableDelayedExpansion` is to avoid problems with exclamation marks and carets, when the password is assinged to `pwd`.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "pwd=fAh""Cog1H!V2%%xaH"   

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "pwd=!pwd:\=\\!"  
set "pwd=!pwd:""=\"!"  This convert double double quotes to an escaped double quotes
java ... set_password "sysadmin" "!pwd!" || exit /b
```

The double quote problem is solved by first doubling all quotes and later convert them for the java argument parser to `\"`.

Probably the backslash itself has to be doubled to prevent further problems, not for batch but for the java argument parser.

Comment: I think to add to this, ensure that the variable comes from external because if you create the variable internally, it will throw away the `%` in password if you have only 1 `%`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Therefore, I wrote `double all percents and double all quotes`, or did you mean something different?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have been more clear. the OP wants to dynamically double the `%` not manually, so if you set password variable in the script as `psw=P%ssword` it will echo `Pssword` even in delayedexpansion, unless the variable comes from external.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks, an unchanged password can only be handled by a read file functionallity and then it has to be stored somehow in a file from the *vague interface*